# Devise views not rendering, Rails 5 in API config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I can't seem to get devise views to render when trying to access rails admin dashboard. They just don't render, status 200 on request.

Here is the console output when I got to `localhost:3001/admin` and it redirects me to `users/sign_in`.

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2019-06-10 13:00:26 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

`rails_admin.rb` config.

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    config.authenticate_with do
      warden.authenticate! scope: :user
    end
    config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
  end
```

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
  root :to => "home#index"
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :sources
      resources :stamps
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure where to go from here, Googling is sending me around in circles. Any ideas?

I have tried overwritting the controllers, I have also dumped the views via `rails g devise:vews` but nothing.

Comment: Was the app generated with the `--api` flag?

Comment: Yep. It is purely an API, I need the dashboard with secure login because the dataset is going to grow. It was originally a seed with 97 entries but I now have another 150+.

Comment: Can you access other rails admin views and get a 404?

Comment: They all redirect to  `/users/sign_in`. I have resorted to HTTPBasic for the moment.